# Can't retrieve cookies in PHP

Tags: php, cookies

I have the following code, in a successful login function:

```
setcookie('username', $username, time()+60*60*24*365);
setcookie('password', $clean_pw, time()+60*60*24*365);
```

Where `$username` and `$clean_pw` are the plain text login information.

In a test page, I try this:

```
foreach ($_COOKIE as $key=>$val)
{
    echo $key.' is '.$val."<br>\n";
}
```

And get as result:

```
PHPSESSID is 823fc1084766daba506cffc3654e1e23
_gat is 1
_ga is GA1.2.1524905679.1454061204
```

Why can't I find my login cookies?

edit: also, the cookies *are* in my browser cookies list. It looks like they aren't in the `$_COOKIE`

Comment: cookies are available on the next page load, you know that?

Comment: shouldn't reloading the same page lead to the same result?

Comment: Never set usernames and passwords in cookies. Cookies can be stolen.

Comment: it should. var_dump($_REQUEST) and $_SERVER, look there. And read above comment - never save username/password in a cookie

Comment: @jgroenen so how would you solve an automatic login? I'm doing this for a small project so I don't think such high security is required.

Comment: Do you run php with [error_reporting=E_ALL|E_STRICT](http://docs.php.net/errorfunc.configuration#ini.error-reporting) and have an eye on the file given in the [error_log](http://docs.php.net/errorfunc.configuration#ini.error-log)? Do you get `headers already sent` messages in that file?

Comment: automatic login, if security isnt a concern, in cookie save some random hash value, and in the database for that user save it too, when you come to page you check the value and see which user in DB has it, and you authenticate him. But its not secure.

Comment: `so how would you solve an automatic login?` you'd store an additional token in both the database and a cookie. This token would be kept in sync but updated regularly. This token would act as the password, except for operations like "change password" or similar.

Comment: You can store some user information in the session.

Comment: (Don't put the credentials in the session. Instead, put the corresponding user-id in the session.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `$_COOKIE` needs to be created using `setcookie()`:

```
setcookie(name, value, expire, path, domain, secure, httponly);
```

More information on `$_COOKIE` at http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp.

---

You can use a PHP Session instead to make it more secure.

Firstly, set the `$_SESSION`:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
header("Location: login.php");
```

To find out if users are logged in, you can check for the session, if not set, then redirect users back to the Login Page.

```
<?php

 session_start();
 if(!$_SESSION['logged_in']){
 session_destroy();
 header("Location: login.php");
}

?>
```

To logout, destroy the Session.

```
<?php

session_start();
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = 0;
session_destroy();
header("Location: login.php");

?>
```

Just a tip, you should encrypt the users' usernames and passwords.

Also, never store passwords in cookies or sessions, as there's no use in the first place. It's a better and more secure way to just store `true` when user is logged in.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, never EVER set usernames or passwords into cookies. It's a very bad practise as cookies can read by anything. A cookie should be used for something like a "remember me" check, and use a session (that still doesn't contain username or password) to verify the users identity.

With that out of the way, to answer your question, You wont see a cookie that's just been set until you go to the next page (or refresh).

Also, you might also want to consider using the dateTime() class for use in date setting and to set up path and domain for the cookie aswell, like so:

```
setcookie(name,value,expire,path,domain,secure,httponly);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set cookie with 'path'.

setcookie(name,value,expire,path,domain,secure,httponly);

like

```
setcookie('username', $username, time()+60*60*24*365, '/');
setcookie('password', $clean_pw, time()+60*60*24*365, '/');
```

which will specify to all file path on that domain.

Answer (score -1):

you can use session instead of cookies, it may help u

```
$_SESSION["name"] = "andy";
$_SESSION["pass"] = "00000";
```

Comment: Don't put the credentials in the session. Instead, put the corresponding user-id in the session.